# The process could not connect to Subscriber 'xxxxxx'

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication, database-mirroring

i have configured `transnational push replication` from SQL Server 2014 to Azure SQL Database
publisher DB is also configured for mirroring.

i get `The process could not connect to Subscriber 'xxxxxx'`
when i see in replication monitor in tab "distributor to subscriber"
[image]

i have used windows user credential everywhere other then for connecting to azure sql database.

note: same setup from new server to same azure db. it works so may be some issue with my production server... i am not sure what?
i got opened all ports listed here 
TCP: 21,80,139, 445
UDP: 137, 138
and also 1433

i am able to connect azure db in SSMS on the same server so azure is not blocking the ip

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check the build version of your SQL Server 2014? Replication to SQL DB is supported in SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU3 or SQL Server 2014 RTM CU10 or higher version. Error MSSQL_REPL20084 and MSSQL_REPL40532 may indicate you are using an older version of SQL Server.

Comment: This is the version we have:
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)   Feb 20 2014 20:04:26   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: can we upgrade to CU10 on production ?

Comment: After hours of struggling why I got the standard Azure message about client IP no present in firewall rules, I finally found this answer leading me in the right direction.
We were running SQL Server 2014 RTM without any service packs. After the seamless update to SP2, the distribution agent immediately progressed. Thanks

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?  For example, I am trying to replicate from SQL Server 2012 to my Azure SQL database but I am getting the same error (although I can connect to it directly from the server after adding the firewall rule in the Azure Portal).  Does SQL Server 2012 not support replication to Azure SQL?  I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15) but it doesn't say anything about Azure SQL, just SQL 2019.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/replication-to-sql-database?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#versions